# same image shows different color on top and bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

i ran across something i have never seen before. the page has a top div and a footer div. both with an image as background. mirrored the image as well via photoshop.

now the weird thing is, it shows a different color. see http://www.hp-consultants.nl

when i tilt my screen towards me the colors become the same. even in photoshop i notice the difference. does anyone know what is wrong?

ive tried using regular CSS colors instead of a background image, to no effect. even the same image shows a difference

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your page. Using Photohop's colour picker confirms that the colours are both indeed exactly the same.

The effect probably happens because you're sitting in front of a TFT monitor, whose display is sensitive to the angle you look at it from.

Some useful background information:

- [LCD Test: Viewing angle](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/viewing_angle.php)
- [Wikipedia on TFT LCDs:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD)

  > TN displays suffer from limited viewing angles, especially in the vertical direction. Colors will shift when viewed off-perpendicular. In the vertical direction, colors will shift so much that they will invert past a certain angle.

Comment: +1 pekka thank you for lcd test. hmmm.. not so thankful as i scrolled down :)

Answer (score 0):

The colours are exactly the same a quick check with any image editor will tell you that.  TFT Monitors can do strange things to colours depending on the viewing angle.

Also our eyes and brains are really not as good at determining colour as we think.  Have you ever seen this optical illusion.

[image: The Squares Labeled A & B are the same colour]

The Squares Labeled A & B are the same colour

Answer (score 0):

may be is the orientation of the led, that brights differently. have you tried to get the browser windows to the bottom of the screen so you see the header where the footer is.

Try this:

- open 2 browser instances
- resize the window of each to view only the header or the footer (one for each)
- place the footer window at the top and the header window at the top
- switch window places

in my case I see the bottom one always more clear.

Hope this helps you